# GPS coordinates coming from vehicle connect to streets coordinates

Tags: qgis, python, sql, geography

I have two tables:

- *"Vehicle"* includes GPS coordinates from the moving vehicles and has around 3.000.000 rows
- *"streetCoordinates"* includes GPS coordinates of the streets, where the vehicles were possibly driving. Its length is around 1.800.000 rows

I want to check, whether the vehicles were on the roads or not. I wrote a query but the thing is, it always fails because it is calculating Cartesian Product - it is checking if there is a match for every point from one table to every point in another table.

Is there any other way to come to a conclusion, which GPS coordinates fall on streets and which do not? Is there a way to do this in QGIS or any other software? Is it possible to this graphically? Up until now, I was using BigQuery and Python for data manipulation and QGIS.

Comment: First off you might have to use a projected coordinates because some tools won't support geographic coordinates. Do you need strict comparaison or do you want all points that are x-meters close to road points/lines ? Do you have lines of points for your streets or just points linked to a street ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! The idea was to assign TRUE/FALSE whether on street or not for every point coming from the vehicle while using radius 6 around the GPS street coordinate, so i don't need strict comparison. So far i only have points of streets with no connection of lines between them.

Comment: are you willing to project your gps coordinates to a crs with coordinates in meters ?

Comment: Sure, if this is a way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Import both tables as layers in Qgis (either throught a csv extract
   or data base import)
2. save both layer as ESRI Shapefile (Right Click on layer -> Export -> Save Features as) with a CRS in meters (find one that can contain every point you have), hopefully the shapefiles won't be too huge
3. load those shapefiles into qgis, go into the properties of both layers and generate a spatial index for both layers (Layer Properties > Source > Geometry and Coordinate Reference System > Create Spatial Index
4. In the "Processing Toolbox" select "Buffer" tool and set it up like the picture under and click run

[image]

5. go into the properties of the created "Buffered" layer and generate a spatial index for this layer also
6. In the "Processing Toolbox" select "Extract by location" and set it up like
   the picture under and click run

[image]

7. You should now have a layer with the points that are 6 meters away from your street points or less

[image]

Comment: Amazing. On my way to do it.

Comment: make sure you have the 64 bit version of QGIS otherwise 100% chance of qgis running out of memory with the amount of points you have

Comment: update: i cut-off the data in order to work with less points. When it comes to creating a buffer, Processing algorithm comes to 99% and then freeze. I'll keep on trying with different variations

Comment: you might want to try to uncheck "Dissolve result", its not strickly necessary for your use case, it just make that step slower to make the next one potentially much much faster

Comment: I came to an end but the problem is, i do not see any layers anymore. I'll try once again.

Comment: I find qgis has trouble with big displaying big shapfiles; in the tools i showed you you can save to a shapefile instead of creating a layer in the memory of qgis by giving a path, you can then load that shapefile separately. That has helped me a few times when having this kind of trouble, and saving intermediate results can't hurt

Comment: Thanks for the update. I solved previously mentioned issue the way i first changed CRS for the whole project and then saved shapefiles into desired CRS format. I am currently waiting for the last step to be processed.

Comment: Your procedure worked for me!! Thanks a lot, i hope it will help others as well!